# Symfony2 duplicate the id in 2 fields (id and idbis) with strategy="AUTO"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like symfony/doctrine to duplicate the id in two different field every time a record is created.
Is it possible in one shot (I use Stragegy="AUTO") ?
If yes how can I do this?

For instence I would like my entity CATEGORY to have two attribut id (auto).
on named id, the other idbis.

(In my exemple I work on a entity which contains parent and children records, so I also have idparent to link the children categories with their parent category)

if the record is a parent Category, then id and idbis get the same integer:
 => id=2, idbis=2, idParent = NULL

if the record is a child Category (let say its parent is Category with id=2) then:
 => id=3, idParent=2, idCategory1=2

That would be great because then I could then easily retrieve all categories (parent and children) who are linked to category which id is 2.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look to Nested Set structures. It's made to easily retrieve sub elements in a simple query by using bounds.

Otherwise you can do that by creating a trigger on insert/update.

Comment: OK I will have a look. which way is the easier? I think I will start with the trigger on insert/update.

Comment: Trigger is the easiest way. Nested Set is powerful but a little tricky at the beginning. In Symfony 1.4 Nested Set were supported so I think it would be supported in Symfony 2 / Doctrine too.

Comment: OK k4timini. I will have a look at trigger on insert and post how I solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relation with the entity itself:

```
<?php
/** @Entity **/
class Category
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
     **/
    private $children;


    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
     **/
    private $parent;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: It won't work as well as Nested Set. You're defining a classical parent/child relationship.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question. I already have set up the relationnship between the children category and parent category. My question is about the duplication of a field which value is loaded in AUTO mode by doctrine. simply would like to retrieve this value.

Comment: As I said you can create a SQL trigger on insert event. After inserting the row, it will perform an update to load the auto generated value to the required attribute.

Comment: would it be a good idea to do it directly in the controller. I mean after having flushed the category, retrieve its id like that mylastrecord->getId() and then set the idbis and the flush again? or is it bad way to do it? if bad how bad is it?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a complete version of the good idea presented by @Markus. Basically parent_id is null for a main category, otherwise has as value the id of parent.

```
  /**
  * @var integer
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
  * @ORM\Id
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
  */
  private $id;

  /**
  * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
  *
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="path\to\Entity\Categories", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"persist"})
  */
  private $children;

  /**
   * @var path\to\Entity\Categories
   *
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="path\to\Entity\Categories", inversedBy="children")
   * @ORM\JoinColumns({
   *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
   * })
   */
   private $parent;
```